# Compile error in Xamarin.iOS project error MSB4018: The "UnpackLocalFrameworks" task failed unexpectedly / System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms application. For a few days Visual Studio has been giving me an error that makes it unable to compile the iOS project. This is the error:

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018: The "UnpackLocalFrameworks" task failed unexpectedly.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018:    at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.MoveFileInPlace(Boolean fileExistsBeforeExtraction, String targetFileName, String tmpPath, Boolean checkLaterForResetDirTimes) in C:\projects\dotnetzip-semverd\src\Zip.Shared\ZipEntry.Extract.cs:line 867
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018:    at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.InternalExtractToBaseDir(String baseDir, String password, ZipContainer zipContainer, ZipEntrySource zipEntrySource, String fileName) in C:\projects\dotnetzip-semverd\src\Zip.Shared\ZipEntry.Extract.cs:line 733
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018:    at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile._InternalExtractAll(String path, Boolean overrideExtractExistingProperty) in C:\projects\dotnetzip-semverd\src\Zip.Shared\ZipFile.Extract.cs:line 259
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018:    at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.ExtractAll(String path, ExtractExistingFileAction extractExistingFile) in C:\projects\dotnetzip-semverd\src\Zip.Shared\ZipFile.Extract.cs:line 222
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.iOS.Local.Tasks.UnpackLocalFrameworks.Execute() in C:\A\1\34\s\src\MSBuild\Xamarin.iOS.Local.Tasks\Tasks\UnpackLocalFrameworks.cs:line 61
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets(73,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

I don't know what is `C:\projects\dotnetzip-semverd\src\Zip.Shared` path.

Some information:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.10.4 (updated last week)
- Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (Build 19041)

Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets file content in error line (73):

```
<UnpackLocalFrameworks
    ReferencedAssemblies="@(AssembliesWithFrameworks)"
    IntermediateOutputPath="$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)">

    <Output TaskParameter="Frameworks" ItemName="_UnpackedFramework" />
</UnpackLocalFrameworks>
```

I don't know what more information I can give.

Comment: Did you use dotnetzip package into your project? The path seems to be related to this https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd

Comment: Hello Dylan, I don't use this library. It doesn't appear in the project references.

Comment: What path is your code located? This could be an issue with a path being created that exceeds the limit allowed on windows. I usually stick my projects in `D:\\dev` to help prevent this. You can also increase the path character limit in the registry. The library errors in the stack trace are those from the Xamarin iOS build so that is a dependency from the tooling you are using FYI :)

Comment: It is nothing related with the path, it's length is less than 100 characters.

Comment: I solved the problem removing obj and bin folders

Comment: For me it's because the path is too long (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem **removing obj and bin folders**.

Note: Build > Clean Solution doesn't work.